# Each div full browser size

Tags: html, css

Ok, I am a bit stuck on this one and can't seem to figure out!

So I am looking for a similar solution, that Apple uses, when they present the specifications of a product.

What I want to achieve is that you have two divs, each of them is taking full space of the browser!

So you would have

<--div1-->
Which is full browser width and height, no problem here by setting the 100%
<--div-->

and then the second div under-neat

<--div2-->
The user has used it's scroll wheel and is outmatically snapped to this div, which is also full size of the browser! How doable is this?
<--div-->

Hope this makes sense :)

I been asked to provide some code:

So I guess the HTML is:

```
<div id="contentOne">
   Just some content
</div>

<div id="contentTWO">
   Just some other content
</div>
```

and then the CSS

```
html {
min-height:100%
}

body {
height:100%

#ContentOne {
min-height:100%;
}

#ContentTwo {
min-height:100%; !--well this doesn't work--!
}
```

Hope this makes sense now!

Comment: YOUR QUEStion is not clear and where is the `css` code ?

Comment: The CSS in your question doesn't work, because you have a couple of errors. 1) `min-height` instead of `height` doesn't work for calculating what the height will be. Give `html` a `height`. 2) There is a missing `}` after the style for the body, and 3) class and id names are case sensitive, so the CSS selectors must match the HTML attributes exactly. (Also, CSS comment delimiters are `/*` .. `*/`, not `!--` .. `--!`, but I'm sure that comment there is not part of your stylesheet...) When you do that, the divs will have the right height, and all you need to do is implement the scroll routine...

Comment: That was just a quick CSS, mate! I know about those errors :) So HTML height to 100% and missing the scroll routine! Cheers MR ^_^